# filter a list of lists : basic thing

Tags: list, scala

Do you know why this program does not give expected answer `(List(3,3))` ?

```
val l=List(List(1,2),List(3,3))
println(l.filter(_ match{
    case u::v => u==v
    case _ => false
}))
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
case u::v => u==v
```

Here, `u` is of type `Int`, while `v` is of type `List[Int]`. They cannot be equal.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way of coding this, that would be useful if you might be dealing with lists of arbitrary length and want to filter down to only those lists with all elements the same, would be:

```
l.filter(ls => !ls.isEmpty && ls.forall(_ == ls.head))
```

(the `!ls.isEmpty` fragment presumes you would wish to exclude empty lists)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the first two elements from your sublists and compare them, you need two `::` in your `case`:

```
l.filter { 
  case u :: v :: _ => u == v
  case _ => false
}
```

If you want to make sure all elements of the sublists are equal, you could use `forall`:

```
l.filter {
  case h :: Nil => false // if you want to exclude single elements
  case h :: r => r.forall(_ == h)
  case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the documentation of [class ::](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.%24colon%24colon). The constructor argument it takes are `(hd: B, tl: List[B])`

In your case `u` becomes `hd` and `v` is `List[In]`. And doing `u==v` is like doing `hd.equals(list)` which gives wrong result.

```
scala> val l= List(List(1,2),List(3,3),List(1),List(1,2,3),List(4,4,4,4))
l: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 3))

scala> l.filter(_ match{
    case u::v =>  Some(u) == v.headOption
    case _ => false
})
res8: List[List[Int]] = List(List(3, 3), List(4, 4, 4, 4))
```

The above is an idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: thanks for all your answers, finally it was possible using u::v::_ or with options; nevertheless, I prefered to use tuples : (a,b,c).